# Working With Content Approval / Moderation In CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, content-approval

The SharePoint Object Model provides a property of an `SPListItem` called `SPListItem.ModerationInformation.Status` to allow you to determine the current content approval / moderation status if a document library has content approval enabled. The property `ModerationInformation` is an instance of the [`class SPModerationInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationinformation.aspx) and `Status` is an instance of the [`enum SPModerationStatusType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype.aspx).

How can I work with these objects / properties from the Client Side Object Model? The client side `ListItem` does not contain the `ModerationInformation` property like its server-side counter part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though the CSOM `ListItem` class does not have a `ModerationInformation` property, I was able to access this value through the field's internal name:

```
ListItem item = file.Item;
clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

int status = Convert.ToInt32(item["_ModerationStatus"]);
```

And the enum is defined as:

```
public enum SPModerationStatusType
{
    Approved, //0
    Denied,   //1
    Pending,  //2
    Draft,    //3
    Scheduled //4
 }
```

This got me where I needed to be.

Comment: As a side note when using REST use `item["OData__ModerationStatus"] ` instead of `item["_ModerationStatus"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Here is the full list of Internal Column name :

    https://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2008/08/21/sharepoint-internal-field-names/

public enum Status
{
    Approved, //0
    Denied,   //1
    Pending,  //2
    Draft,    //3
    Scheduled //4
 }

    ListItem item = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('listname').AddItem(listObj);
    clientContext.Load(item);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    item["_ModerationStatus"] =  Convert.ToInt32(Status.Approved);
    item.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

```
//Getting access to the SP file.
File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
ListItem listItems = home.ListItemAllFields;
ctx.Load(listItems);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


//Approval Status could be the follwoing: Approved => 0, Denied => 1, Pending => 2, Draft => 3, Scheduled => 4
int status = Convert.ToInt32(listItems["_ModerationStatus"]);
```