# CSOM Get ListItem of Folder

Tags: client-object-model, folder, list-item, content-approval

In an application I'm working on, I'm interacting with SharePoint (2010) via the .NET Client-Side Object Model, and am trying to account for a large number of possible configurations of document libraries.

In the instance that a document library has content approval enabled, if I create a new `Folder` object, the approval status applies to this `ListItem` as well:

[image: Newly Created Folder]

How can I get a reference to the `ListItem` that is the newly created `Folder` object?

I need to set this value to `SPModerationStatusType.Approved` programmatically when I create a new folder, but can't find a way to modify the fields of the `ListItem` given that I only have a `Folder` object.

I want to get a `ListItem` object so I can do something like this:

[Working With Content Approval / Moderation In CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57058/working-with-content-approval-moderation-in-csom)

## Edit:

For SharePoint 2013, they've apparently taken this into consideration and have added a [`Folder.ListItemAllFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields.aspx) property which would be exactly what I need here, but this property is unavailable to the 2010 CSOM.

Comment: can you please put the entire code.. as for me the query is showing null. I want to edit the _approval status as approved for folders/ subfolder recursivly.can you please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by using a `CamlQuery` directly after creation to return folders with the same name as a `ListItemCollection`:

```
SP.CamlQuery query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                  "<Query>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                      "<And>" +
                        "<Eq>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>" +
                          "<Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +
                        "<Eq>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>" +
                          "<Value Type='Text'>" + subFolderName + "</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +
                      "</And>" +
                    "</Where>" +
                  "</Query>" +
                "</View>";

SP.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(items);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

With a little validation of the item I can set the property as I need.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to recommend using of "FileRef" (folder directory) instead of "FileLeafRef" (folder name).