# Is there a way to get Folder object from ListItem one?

Tags: development, client-object-model, caml-query

This is my first post, so I'd like to say hello to everyone.

I'm trying to get Folder object by its path in SharePoint 2010 client application using Client Side Object Model (.Net 4.0).

I need to check whether folder described by 'folderPath' variable exists in the library and then get the Folder object for further operations. To enhance performance, I chose to use CAML query to filter the list.

My code:

```
IEnumerable<List> library = this.clientContext.LoadQuery(
    this.clientContext.Web.Lists.Where(p => p.Title == this.documentLibrary));
this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
List libraryList = library.FirstOrDefault();
//code to handle libraryList == null

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml =
   "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">" +
       "<Query>" +
           "<Where>" +
               "<And>" +
                   "<Eq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\"/>" +
                      "<Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value>" +
                   "</Eq>" +
                   "<Eq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\" />" +
                      "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + folderPath + "</Value>" +
                   "</Eq>" +
               "</And>" +
           "</Where>" +
       "</Query>" +
   "</View>";

ListItemCollection items = libraryList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(items);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

To this point everything is OK. But I don't have any idea how get the 'Folder' object from an item. I tried to do it in this way:

```
Folder folder = items.FirtsOrDefault().Folder;
clientContext.Load(folder);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

and that way (used instead of last three lines from first code snippet):

```
ListItemCollection items = libraryList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(items, collection => collection.Include(item => item.Folder));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But in both cases I got an Exception:

1st: 'Field or property 'Folder' does not exist.'

2nd: 'Column 'Folder' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.'

Is there a way to do it? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSOM Get ListItem of Folder](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57188/csom-get-listitem-of-folder)

Comment: Don't know what is better: possible duplicate or answering your own question after half an hour: [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57188/csom-get-listitem-of-folder), and an hour: [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57058/working-with-content-approval-moderation-in-csom) :)

Comment: I retracted that close vote because your question is different; it's almost the reverse of the one in the auto-generated comment. But there's nothing wrong with answering your own questions. It just means I figured it out myself before someone else answered. Even still, asking a question and answering it in one fell swoop is still supported, and is given as an option via the UI when asking a question (that's what the checkbox marked "Answer your own question" is for). See: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/386/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-you-intend-to-answer-immediately

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually depends on which version of SharePoint is used.

### SharePoint 2013

In SharePoint 2013 CSOM [ListItem.Folder property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.folder%28v=office.15%29.aspx) gets a folder object that is associated with a folder item.

### SharePoint 2010

In SharePoint 2010 CSOM Folder property is **not** exposed for [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem%28v=office.15%29.aspx) object.

The following method could be used for retrieving `Folder` associated with `ListItem`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Parent Folder for List Item
/// </summary>
/// <param name="listItem"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static Folder GetListItemFolder(ListItem listItem)
{
    var folderUrl = (string)listItem["FileDirRef"];
    var parentFolder = listItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
    listItem.Context.Load(parentFolder);
    listItem.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    return parentFolder;
}
```

Example:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
      var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
      var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
      context.Load(items);
      context.ExecuteQuery();


      foreach (var item in items)
      {
         var folder = GetListItemFolder(item); //get Folder
         Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
      }
}
```

Comment: So there is no other way than using `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` method?

Comment: I believe this is the only way, if you need to get Folder object associated with ListItem object in SPS 2010

Comment: I did not notice that I am using wrong `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` dlls to communicate with SP 2010. I created my project with VS 2013 and referenced dlls were in 15.0.0.0 version. That's why I got `Folder` property in ListItem object (which is available in SP 2013). After change dlls reference to 14.0.0.0 version `Folder` property is not available any more. Your post helped me to understand this problem, so I will check it as an answer (despite the fact that Camerons post with `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` method was the first one).

Comment: It doesn't matter which answer is first. You should accept the best answer, and upvote any answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyserverrelativeurl%28v=office.15%29.ASPX):

```
clientContext.Load(libraryList.RootFolder, spFolder => spFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var folderServerRelativePath = string.Format("0}/{1}",
  libraryList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'), 
  folderPath.TrimStart('/')
);
clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderServerRelativePath)
```

You can use the same approach you started with to filter, but then you'd need the libraryList.RootFolder.Folders property.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to mark your answer as useful at the moment.

Comment: Kinda the same as what the other guy answered after me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

To get the folder you have to user `SPFolder` instead of Folder.

```
    SPFile fItem= item.Web.GetFile(item.Url);  
    SPFolder folder = fItem.ParentFolder;
```

Try this if it works.

**Edit**

To get folder of each item you should place the code in `foreach()` loop

Comment: I am not able to use SPFile/SPFolder since I'm using client side object model. 'SP*' classes are only available on the server side.