# SharePoint Webhooks : Get the ID of the newly created folder using ChangeQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-handlers, changelog, webhooks

My scenario: I have setup a webhook on a list and each time a new folder is created,my azure function is called(which is acting as the notification hub),where i am using the changequery to get the changes on the list.I am able to get the **ObjectType** and **ChangeType** of the event that occured in the SPList,buti am not able to figure out how to find out the **ids** of the newly created folder and hence do some manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
try {
    log.Info("Executing function");

    using (var ctx = await csomHelper.GetClientContext("ur url to a site"))
    {

   ListCollection list = ctx.Web.Lists; 
    List targetlist = list.GetByTitle("Company"); 
    ChangeQuery cq = new ChangeQuery(false, false);
    cq.Item = true;
    cq.Folder = true;
    cq.File = true;

    cq.List = true;           
    cq.Add = true;           
    ctx.Load(list);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    ChangeCollection coll = targetlist.GetChanges(cq);
    ctx.Load(coll);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     foreach (Change change in coll)
            {
                if (change is ChangeItem)
                {

                    ListItem changedListItem = targetlist.GetItemById((change as ChangeItem).ItemId); 
                    ctx.Load(changedListItem); 
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    Folder folder=changedListItem.Folder;
                    ctx.Load(folder); 
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    log.Info("folder is "+folder.UniqueId);


                }


            }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a step by step article in [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38062.sharepoint-online-simulate-sharepoint-timer-jobs-and-event-receivers-using-azure-functions-and-sharepoint-webhooks.aspx#SharePoint_Webhooks_as_Event_Receivers) that simulates **SharePoint Webhooks as Event Receivers** for SharePoint Online List. You can find the implementation under the heading *SharePoint Webhooks as Event Receivers* in the above mentioned article.

You can get the item id as **(change as ChangeItem).ItemId}** . Please see the below code :

```
foreach (Change change in changes)
               {
                   if (change is ChangeItem)
                      {
                       ListItem changedListItem = changedList.GetItemById((change as ChangeItem).ItemId); 
                       SPClientContext.Load(changedListItem); 
                       SPClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                       string emailBody = "<b>New Change in the SLA List</b> </br><table style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
                       emailBody +=   "<table style='border: 1px solid black;'><tr style='color:green;'><td>ID :"+ (change as ChangeItem).ItemId +" -- </td><td><b> Action Item : "+ changedListItem["Title"]+"</b></td><td> -- SLA : "+ changedListItem["SLADate"]+"</td></tr>";
                       emailBody +=  "</table>"; 

                       Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.EmailProperties emailProperties = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.EmailProperties();
                       emailProperties.To = new string[] { "Priyaranjan@SharePointChronicle.com" };
                       emailProperties.Subject = "Attention : A new modification has occurred in the SLA List";
                       emailProperties.Body = emailBody;
                       Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail(SPClientContext, emailProperties);

                       SPClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            log.Info($"A list item with ID : { (change as ChangeItem).ItemId} is {change.ChangeType.ToString() }" );
                      }
               }
```

As you can see I have got the item ID in the Azure Logs : 
[image]

**Updated**

To answer your question on how to get the folder from the list item id, you can create the list item object and cast it to the folder object using ListItem.Folder property

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93052/is-there-a-way-to-get-folder-object-from-listitem-one)

Comment: at this point i get the id as you suggested,but now if i do something like getfolderByid() it ask for a guid?? any idea how to solve that

Comment: getfolderByid() will need a GUID. Instead you can get the ListItem object using the id and then get the folder object using ListItem.Folder property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.folder(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: thanks i think this will work,if you do have the code snippet ,it will help

Comment: this is my implementation but something not working,could you have a look . https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223110/changequery-unable-to-read-changeitem