# Changequery not displaying all changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, changelog, getchanges

My scenario  is i have a list of companies and each time am creating a new company(folder),i should be able to use the changequery method to identify the company created and create a document set inside it. i can get the number of changes correctly using the first log.Info() but  log.Info("folder is "+folder.Name); is displaying only the first folder i created!!!

```
try {
    log.Info("Executing function");

    using (var ctx = await csomHelper.GetClientContext("site url"))
    {


    ListCollection list = ctx.Web.Lists; 
    List targetlist = list.GetByTitle("Companies"); 
    log.Info("");
    ChangeQuery cq = new ChangeQuery(false, false);
    cq.Item = true;
    cq.Folder = true;
    cq.File = true;

    cq.List = true;           
    cq.Add = true;           
    ctx.Load(targetlist);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    ChangeCollection coll = targetlist.GetChanges(cq);
    ctx.Load(coll);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    log.Info(coll.Count.ToString());

     foreach (Change change in coll)
            {
                if (change is ChangeItem)
                {

                    ListItem changedListItem = targetlist.GetItemById((change as ChangeItem).ItemId); 
                    ctx.Load(changedListItem); 
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                  if (changedListItem.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder){

                    Folder folder=changedListItem.Folder;
                    ctx.Load(folder); 
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    log.Info("folder is "+folder.Name);



                    ctx.Load(targetlist,l => l.RootFolder,l => l.ContentTypes);                
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    var ctData = targetlist.ContentTypes.Where(c => c.Name == "thirdcorporate");
                    var contentType = ctData.FirstOrDefault();
                    ctx.Load(contentType);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    DocumentSet.Create(ctx, folder, "newshi Documents", contentType.Id);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

}  else
  {
     log.Info("not a folder");
  }